# Sharepoint Alert to the item creator

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to set up alerts to go to the item creator whenever the item is added or edited .

Please help me send alerts using j query or event handler

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: i have created a sharepoint list with alerts to selected users but i also want to add the item creator to the alert list so that he/she is notified when an item is added or modified on the list

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: i am using SharePoint 2013
PS i dont have access to the sharepoint designer

Comment: its kinda urgent can you help?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you have three options I believe.

One is a workflow which sends an E-Mail to the creator of the document everytime the item is edited an updated. Since you don't have access to SharePoint designer this isn't really possible.

The second is to have an ItemAdded event handler coded and added to the list which sets up an alert for the document owner. If you don't have access to SP designer then it's unlikely you will be able to deploy a fully trusted solution.

The other option is if the user is actually interested is to show them how to do it manually. 9/10 people who have alerts forced upon them will set up a rule within their inbox to delete the notification.

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0):

You can create ItemAdded and ItemUpdated event receiver to send mail alerts to the item Author, please check the demo below:

[Writing EventReceivers SharePoint Lists](https://nasironline.wordpress.com/tag/send-email-alert-event-receiver/)

Comment: thanks for sharing this.
can you please let me know where to paste this script and where to modify to send it to the item author